# MySQL Selecting MAX total with date and ID

Tags: mysql, reporting, max

I have a cron script that writes the total number of active users to a table every day. I'm trying to now generate a simple report that would show the "high water mark" for each month. Because some accounts expire during the month it's possible the highest number may NOT be at the end of the month.

Here's a sample of my table structure

```
tblUserLog
-----------
record_id   INT(11)   // PRIMARY KEY
run_date    DATE      // DATE RUN
ttl_count   INT(11)   // TOTAL FOR DAY
```

Sample data:

```
record_id      run_date      ttl_count
1              2013-06-01    500
2              2013-06-10    510
3              2013-06-20    520
4              2013-06-30    515
5              2013-07-01    525
6              2013-07-10    530
7              2013-07-20    540
8              2013-07-31    550
9              2013-08-01    560
```

What I would like returned is:

```
record_id   run_date        ttl_count
3           2013-06-20      520
8           2013-07-31      550
9           2013-08-01      560
```

I've tried two queries that are close...

```
// This will give me the total for the first of the month
SELECT s.record_id, s.run_date, s.ttl_count
FROM tblStatsIndividual s
JOIN (
    SELECT record_id
    FROM tblStatsIndividual
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(run_date, '%Y %m')
    HAVING MAX(ttl_count)
) s2
ON s2.record_id = s.record_id
ORDER BY run_date DESC
```

This returns the total for the first of each month, along with the record_id and correct date for the total.

Tried this...

```
SELECT record_id,max(run_date), max(ttl)
FROM (
    SELECT record_id,run_date, max(ttl_count) AS ttl
    FROM tblStatsIndividual
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(run_date, '%Y %m')
) a 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(run_date, '%Y %m')
ORDER BY run_date DESC
```

This one appears to get the correct "high water mark" but it's not returning the record_id, or the run_date for the row that IS the high water mark.

How do you get the record_id and the run_date for the highest total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the help from @Tony Hopkinson, This query gets me the info. The one caveat is it shows the ID and date for the first occurrence of the MAX total, so if the total is the same three days in a row on a month, the first day's ID is returned. For my purpose, the last ID would be more ideal, but I can live with this:

```
SELECT s.Record_ID, s.Run_Date, s.ttl_Count
FROM tblStatsIndividual s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR(run_date) AS yr, MONTH(run_date) AS mon, MAX(ttl_count) AS ttl
    FROM tblStatsIndividual
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(run_date, '%Y %m')
 ) maximums
 ON maximums.yr = YEAR(s.run_date) 
    AND maximums.mon = MONTH(s.run_date) 
    AND maximums.ttl = s.ttl_Count
GROUP BY ttl_count
ORDER BY run_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
Select detail.Record_ID, detail.Run_Date, detail.ttl_Count
From tblStatsIndividual detail
Inner Join
(Select Year(run_date) as Year, Month(Run_date) as Month, Max(ttl_count) as ttl
From tblStatsIndividual
Group By Year(run_date), Month(Run_date)) maximums
On maximums.Year = Year(detail.Run_date) and maximums.Month = Month(detail.Run_date)
and maximums.ttl = detail.ttl_count
```

Should do it. NB based on your requirement if you had two records in the same month with the same (and highest in the month) ttl_count, they would both be returned.

Comment: When I ran this query it gave me every day. I just want the highest one per month/year though...